# Flickr.Net Filter Tags by Predicate Wildcard

Tags: flickr

In the following method

```
flickrTagService.MachineTagsGetRecentValues(nameSpaceName, predicate);
```

I am trying to filter my Tags by a predicate wildcard

```
Namespace = "nycparks"; 
Predicate = “M010”; //ParkId
```

This works as expected and returns all my photos that contain M010 (Central Park NYC) 
Ie: nycparks:m010=1014

Is there a way to Filter the Predicate M* So I can get all the Tags which start with M (Manhattan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Flickr API method does not support partial predicates. The only way you could accomplish this is to retrieve all predicates for that namespace, and then filter them yourself.